# shell rsync: recursively merging filter files

Tags: linux, shell, rsync

I have a filter file '.filter' for rsync with the following contents:

```
merge '../.pattern'
```

The included file '.pattern' in turn also includes other pattern file in its parent directory and has the same contents:

```
merge '../.pattern'
```

When files are included in such a way, rsync apparently goes in infinite recursion and exits with "too many open files" error. Is there a way with rsync to use multiple levels of included files with relative paths?

Comment: What is the goal of this design?  Why, for example, are you storing the filter rules for a directory inside its parent instead of inside itself?  If you want inheritance in the rules you can use `dir-merge` and then the rules will propagate to the child directories.

Comment: The parent directory contains a pattern that is common for most, but not for all of its child directories. Child directories can use only parent pattern, append the parent pattern to its own pattern or not use the parent pattern at all. dir-merge applies only to current and child directories, but if only a child directory must be rsynced, 'dir-merge' will not let to include the parent's filter.